# Any way to get the size of all the files in the recycle bin in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Any way to get the total size of files in the Recycle Bin in windows 7 without having to Select All and hit Properties or More Details?  This was available in the Status bar in XP, is there any add-in or something that can give a brief summary of the Recycle bin in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

If you select all or multiple files up to 15 items, the total size will be displayed in the status bar like usual (similar to Windows XP), however, any more than 15 files, it requires you to press "Show More Details" or right click the files and choose properties to see the total size of the selected files.

After researching for some time (too much time), I was unable to find any other way to see the collective/total size of selected files when more than 15 files were selected other than the "Show more details" option that windows 7 presents, or as many others on the Internet suggest, right clicking and choosing properties.  Both solutions are cumbersome for people that select lots of files at the same time on a regular basis and need or want to know the total size of the selected files.

The only alternative (more invasive) solution I ran across was people suggesting to replace their use of Windows Explorer with programs such as Total Commander, and a few other names I didn't document along the way as I wasn't planning to switch myself, and just live with the issue.

Hope that helps, as I spent way too much time trying to find a configuration option or hack.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a free program named [Rainmeter](http://www.rainmeter.net). Once installed, download the [space craft skin](http://customize.org/rainmeter/skins/86590). It has a Bin icon that shows the total files inside the Recycle Bin at all times. Other skins have different styles of icons.

Comment: @Indrek - thanks for the edit, much better answer now. Having tried it, it does answer the question quite well.

Comment: @Gnoupi No problem, and good to hear it works. I've given the answer a +1 based on your comment.

Comment: Note that the space craft "theme" is not necessary (though it does look quite awesome). In the [default skins](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4K4k0X2itIY/Tq7e6nOx9JI/AAAAAAAAACg/pHwPvnWaizU/s1600/Illustro.jpg) bundled with Rainmeter, there is a "recycle bin" one, which shows the number of files and the total size, as well:

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the total size being removed from the status bar is one of the most frustrating changes to Windows. Not only do you have to click the *Show More* link in the Preview Pane to see information for more than 15 items, but to see the size of the items in the Recycle Bin, you must first select all files in the Recycle Bin, then **deselect all Internet shortcuts**. If you have even one `.URL` file selected, the information will not be shown (why is beyond me).

A much more convenient way is to use the [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/). It provides numerous usability fixes and enhancements as well as to revert various things back to how they worked in XP (including always showing the total size of all items in a folder in the status bar), and even provides a few new features.

Answer (score 0):

If you select all, the total file size of all the selected items should appear in your status bar.  You should not need to hit properties or anything else in order to see the information.

Comment: No, I have to hit properties to see the total size.  Selecting all just gives me "43 items selected, show more details..."

Comment: @KrisErickson - If you press `show more details` it displays the total size of the selected files in question.